# How to open popup with a list of ssl certificates on each browser (IE, firefox, chrome)

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3, certificate, ssl-certificate

I need to open a popup with a list of digital certificates installed on my browser(firefox, IE, chrome). I found really hard to find information about this, I have a proyect in which i have to open a list and choose a certificate depending on the navigator, the proyect is in ionic 3 / angular 7, and then somehow encrypt it and pass it to an external service (i do not know yet what the back have to receive, if a hashed key provided by me or the whole certificate as file, what is the correct way?). I know is a wide question but if you can orient me in how this works will help a lot.

I just look for info on the web because I do not know yet how to achieve this

Comment: I am not sure about which kind of certificates you are intending here, but probably the following discussion can point you to some direction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40424927/how-to-get-certificate-list-using-javascript-or-jquery and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604399/is-there-a-way-to-get-ssl-certificate-details-using-javascript.

Comment: Do you want to stablish a ssl connection with certificate authentication?

Comment: I just want to open a popup with a list of the certificates installed on the computer on the current browser

Comment: javascript does not allow access to the system/browser keystore, so it is not possible to do so. The browser only uses the user's certificates when authentication is required in an SSL connection, and the connection it is managed automatically by the browser